# TypeError: Cannot read property '10' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Why is this getting me the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '10' of undefined` in line 17? I'm building a battleship project that after each click, each box changes the color to another one because it would be like that place getting a shoot. But I'm getting this error on line 17 `const position = currentGrid[x][y];` after I'm trying to look for the currentGrid.

```
import React, {useEffect  ,useState} from 'react'
import Ship from '../components/ShipGenerate.js'
import '../style/style.css'



function Grid(props) {
    const emptyGrid = new Array(10);
    for (let i = 0; i < emptyGrid.length; i += 1) {
        emptyGrid[i] = new Array(10).fill(0);
    }

    const [grid, setGrid] = useState(emptyGrid);

    function togglePieceStatus(x, y) {
        setGrid(currentGrid => {
            const position = currentGrid[x][y];
            currentGrid[x][y] = position === 0 ? 1 : 0;
            return currentGrid;
        });
    }

    const box = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            const className = grid[x][y] === 0 ? 'piece' : 'boom';
            box.push(
                <div>
                    <div
                        className={className}
                        onClick={() => togglePieceStatus(x, y)}
                    ></div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="box">{box}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Grid
```

Comment: Which one is line 17?

Comment: Already mentioned in post. ```const position = currentGrid[x][y];```

Comment: Well, grid is 10x10, so indices will be 0-9, somewhere, somehow, you are passing an index 10. Since I think the `currentGrid` state will be defined I think it's failing on `currentGrid[x]` when it tries to access the `y` "coordinate".

Comment: Try using let instead of var in your double for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Using `var` in the double for-loop is mutating the `x` and `y` values passed to the `togglePieceStatus` callback.

```
function togglePieceStatus(x, y) {
    setGrid(currentGrid => {
        const position = currentGrid[x][y];
                                       ^ error points here
        currentGrid[x][y] = position === 0 ? 1 : 0;
        return currentGrid;
    });
}
```

Each callback was receiving a mutated `x`, `y` value from the loop counter final iteration to 10 from `x++` and `y++`. `currentGrid[x]` was evaluated as `currentGrid[10]` which is undefined and throws the error when attempting to access the `y` index.

## Solution

Use `let` so that they are scoped correctly to each iteration of the for-loop and not hoisted.

```
const box = [];
for (let x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
    const className = grid[x][y] === 0 ? "piece" : "boom";
    box.push(
      <div>
        <div className={className} onClick={() => togglePieceStatus(x, y)}>
          {x},{y}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit heuristic-kilby-o9cux]